# Using firepath/firebug/locator apps for Mozilla, but right click clicks the button

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, right-click

When I use Element Inspector, Firebug, FirePath, or WebDriver Element Locator, I would love to right click and than select my option. The problem is, when I right click, the browser will click any button or link I am mousing over.

Is there a way to disable this?

I am using these commands on a JavaScript web application.

Comment: I know this isn't a direct answer to your question but you can right-click *near* the desired element and then navigate through the DOM to find it.

Comment: I don't know a website where I could test it now. Try setting the following in a FirefoxProfile object: `profile.setPreference("dom.event.contextmenu.enabled", "false")` and check if it disables loading also.